# upgrade Postgres Primary/Standby from 11 to 12

Tags: postgresql

I am trying Postgres upgrade from 11 to 12.

old datadir - /var/lib/pgsql/11/data

new datadir - /var/lib/pgsql/12/data

After upgrading primary using pg_upgrade --link ( primary and standby still down), I issue the rsync command as the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) suggests from primary and above the old and new data dirs.
rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive old_cluster new_cluster remote_dir

In my case,
rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive /var/lib/pgsql/11/data /var/lib/pgsql/12/data test-stdby:/var/lib/pgsql

*--and remote_dir is above the old and new cluster directories on the standby* - as per manual.

However, I see a data directory gets created under /var/lib/pgsql on the standby i.e./var/lib/pgsql/data instead of getting created under /var/lib/pgsql/12

What am I missing?

Also, my postgresql.conf has everything commented and all the custom settings are under conf.d directory that is specified by include_dir ='conf.d' in postgresql.conf
For postgresql12, since primary_connection_info on standby needs to part of postgresql.conf and not recovery.conf, can I simply place recovery.conf file with primary_connect info in my conf.d directory? Any experiences of how that will work?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can't use the rsync method to rebuild your standby for major upgrades, would get datafile incompatibility errors.
pgbasebackup is your best bet. ( much faster too)

Answer (score 0):

The command should rather be:

```
rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive /var/lib/pgsql/11 /var/lib/pgsql/12 test-stdby:/var/lib/pgsql
```